# Can "mov eax, 0x1" always be used instead of "mov rax, 0x1"?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, zero-extension

When assembling this code with `nasm`:

```
BITS 64
mov eax, 0x1
mov rax, 0x1
```

I get this output:

```
b8 01 00 00 00 b8 01 00 00 00
```

which is the opcode for `mov eax, 0x1` repeated twice.

Does this mean that `mov rax, 0x1` can **always** be replaced by `mov eax, 0x1` or is it just in this case?

If this is correct wouldn't it be better to use than:

```
xor rax, rax
inc rax
```

as that becomes 6 bytes when assembled while `mov eax, 0x1` is only 5 bytes?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502839/loading-small-numbers-into-64-bit-x86-registers

Comment: Actually, because the first snippet is correct, the second snippet would only take 4 bytes (no REX prefixes required).

Comment: `xor eax,eax` / `inc eax` is 4B, slightly smaller than `mov eax, 1`.  But don't use that unless you're heavily optimizing for code-size.  Spending 1 byte to save an instruction (and a fused-domain uop) is worth it for modern CPUs.

Comment: you can use [`mov rax, strict dword/qword 1` to force the 7/10-byte version of mov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597025/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always. Most (if not all) 32-bit MOVs and ALU operations clear bits 32 through 63 of the destination register operand. See the CPU manual for details.