# How to generate a KSHIFTRW (Shift Right Mask Registers)

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx512

I have a __mmask64 mask register and I need to chop it into 4 __mmask16 mask registers.

I (incorrectly) assumed that the following line of code would have done the trick:

```
__mmask16 mask_16 = static_cast<__mmask16>(mask_64 >> 16);
```

But I get (Intel c++ compiler 18.0):

```
kmovq       r14,k1  
shr         r15,10h
kmovw       k2,r15d
```

Since the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) does not have a something like _mm512_kshift(k, imm8) and the definition for example _mm512_kand is just:

`#define _mm512_kand(k1, k2) ((__mmask16) ((k1) & (k2)))`

I assumed shifting would have given me a [KSHIFTRW](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/KSHIFTRW_KSHIFTRB_KSHIFTRQ_KSHIFTRD).

**Question**: How to generate a KSHIFTRW with C++.

**Edit**: I just found a related question with a sufficient answer: [Missing AVX-512 intrinsics for masks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167997/missing-avx-512-intrinsics-for-masks)

Comment: This is a missed optimization in most compilers.  gcc/clang/icc almost always move to integer regs and back, even for one instruction they could have done with a `k` instruction.

Comment: Just looked at your original goal again.  You want to unpack one mask to 4.  If you don't need the upper bits zeroed for each mask, that's just 3x `kshiftrq k2/3/4, k1, 16 / 32 / 48`, which is 3 uops for port 5 on Skylake-AVX512.  `kmovw k, r32` also needs port 5, so either way you compete with vector ALU ops.  Moving to GP registers is strictly worse, even if it's clever and uses 3x `rorx` / `kmovw`.

Comment: Unfortunately store/reload isn't viable either: `kmovw k, [mem16]` is 3 uops: load + port5 + any-ALU-port (p0156).  That's according to IACA at least (according to the http://instlatx64.atw.hu/ spreadsheet, although it says `p237`, which is bogus because p7 only has a store-AGU, not a load port.)  Anyway, sounds like `k`-register loads are done as GP-integer loads and then a `kmov` internally.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the valuable info. I guess it is more efficient (in my specific situation) to replace the cmp instruction that gave the 64-bit mask with 4 xmm comparisons that yield 16-bit masks.

Comment: I guess, if you can do that without any extra shuffles.  On SKL-AVX512, if you're not bottlenecked on the front-end, letting the compile move to integer for the unpack is not too bad.