# How can you insert a NaN into a xmm register?

Tags: assembly, x86, nan, sse

For the function I am writing I would like to return a Nan if the input doesn't make sense.

**How can I insert a NaN into an xmm register** the easiest way?

Comment: How do you determine which "input doesn't make sense"? If this is the result of a comparison, you can just bitwise-or your "normal" result with the result-mask of the comparison.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All-ones is a quiet (non-signalling, aka normal) NaN, which is what you want.  The easiest way to produce one is with SSE2 **`pcmpeqd xmm0,xmm0`** to set every bit in the register to `1`, i.e. 2's complement integer `-1`.  ([Set all bits in CPU register to 1 efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105164/set-all-bits-in-cpu-register-to-1-efficiently) / [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly))

It's actually a `-NaN` - the sign bit is set.  Consider integer right shift (`psrld xmm0,1`) or divide by zero / zero (`xorps xmm0,xmm0` / `divpd xmm0,xmm0`) if that's undesirable.

---

**Math functions that want to return NaN often also want to make sure the FP-invalid sticky exception bit gets set** in MXCSR (or actually raise an exception if your caller unmasked that exception).  To do *that*, you can multiply or add the NaN with itself.  e.g.

```
    ...
.error_return_path:
    pcmpeqd   xmm0, xmm0
    mulsd     xmm0, xmm0       ; Cause an FP-invalid operation.
    ret
```

Or `mulss` for single-precision `float`.  `mulpd` / `mulps` would also be appropriate.

The bit-pattern for multiply or add of NaN with NaN is definitely still a NaN, and should still be the same payload, so still all-ones.

Having the return value be a result of `mulsd` or `addsd` (or `divsd`) also has the advantage that if the caller uses that register repeatedly in a loop, it won't have domain-crossing bypass latency.  (On Sandybridge-family, this lasts forever.  e.g. every `addsd xmm1, xmm0` would have an extra cycle of latency from xmm1 input to xmm1 output if xmm0 came from `pcmpeqd`, even if that was long ago and the integer-SIMD uop has already retired.)

---

You might even be able to do it branchlessly if you use `cmpsd` or `cmppd`: you can `orps` that 0 / -1 mask into a result to make it NaN or unchanged.  If some other calculation will (or will have already) set the FP-invalid flag, or if you don't care about that, you're all set.

Beware of lengthening the critical path with extra cmp / or; if you expect it's super rare, you might rather still compare and branch, e.g. with `movmskpd` / `test eax,eax` / `jnz` on a cmppd result to see if either bit was set => one of the SIMD elements failed some check.